# Collect values from an enum with stream doesn't work

Tags: java, java-8, enums, java-stream

I want to have a list with almost all the values from an enum. I tried to do that with the help of stream but I don't know why it is not working.

For example I am trying to do like this:

```
 SortingType.stream() //
            .filter(d -> !d.getName().equals(SortingType.UNKNOWN.getName()))
            .forEach(u -> {
                sortingList.add(createSortingBE(locale, u, u.name().equalsIgnoreCase(sortingType.name())));
            });
```

**.stream()** appears with red and I receive this message : " Cannot resolve method 'stream' in 'SortingType' "

Sorting Type

```
public enum SortingType {
    DISTANCE("DISTANCE", 101, "Sorting POIs by distance"),
    PRICE("PRICE", 104, "Sorting POIS by price"),
    UNKNOWN("UNKNOWN", 000, "Unknown sorting option");

    private String name;
    private Integer identifier;
    private String description;

    SortingType(final String name, final Integer identifier, final String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.identifier = identifier;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public static SortingType getByName(final String name) {
        return Stream.of(values()).filter(u -> u.name.equalsIgnoreCase(name)).findFirst().orElse(SortingType.UNKNOWN);
    }

    public static SortingType getByIdentifier(final Integer identifier) {
        return Stream.of(values()).filter(u -> u.identifier.equals(identifier)).findFirst().orElse(SortingType.UNKNOWN);
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public Integer getIdentifier() {
        return identifier;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
```

Comment: use `SortingTypes.values()`... Cheers

Comment: Because there is no `stream()` method in `SortingType`. The code you’ve posted correctly uses `Stream.of(values())`, two times, so where does the problem occur? Besides that, your `getName()` method is obsolete, the `enum` type does already have a `name()` method returning the name of the constant, further, predicates like `!d.getName().equals(SortingType.UNKNOWN.getName())` are unnecessarily complicate, just use `d != SortingType.UNKNOWN`. Even weirder is `u.name().equalsIgnoreCase(sortingType.name())`, as it shows that you know about `name()`, but why `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `equals`?

Comment: @new_in_programming read the beauty @holger did write above. Also check `Enum.class` in java docs. Good luck.

Comment: You probably want [EnumSet.complementOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumSet.html#complementOf(java.util.EnumSet)):  `EnumSet.complementOf(EnumSet.of(SortingType.UNKNOWN)).stream()`

Comment: @Holger, the problem occur here, SortingType.stream().filter... I saw this exemple https://www.baeldung.com/java-initialize-hashset#using-stream-since-java-8, and I thought that I can do something similar

Comment: I saw this example in a diferent project and it's working perfectly

Comment: SortingType.stream() 
                .filter(s -> !s.equals(SortingType.UNKNOWN) && s.isSortingEnabledForGeometry(queryGeometryBE)
                        && sortingStrategyFactory.get(s).isAccepted(pois, locale)) 
                .forEach(u -> {
                    sortingList.add(createSortingBE(locale, u, u.name().equalsIgnoreCase(sortingType.name())));
                });

Comment: @new_in_programming I suggest reading [the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html) and [the package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#package.description) first, to get an understanding of the API, instead of just copying some code and doing trial-and-error changes.

Comment: @Holger, thank you! I will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply add the `stream()` method like this.

```
public enum SortingType {

    // .....

    public static Stream<SortingType> stream() {
        return Stream.of(values());
    }
}
```